# System.ArgumentException running Windows Forms program in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

I wrote a Windows Forms application in C# using Visual Studio 2010.  It has a tab control with several pages. All pages work correctly in Mono with the exception of one, which, when clicked on, causes the application to terminate with the error displayed below.  You can see the page start to get drawn, then fail.

One note: the only items that are on this page that are not on the others are a `FlowLayoutPanel` and a `ProgressBar`.  There are no fonts that are not on the other pages.  I see `ToolStripMenuItem mentioned` below, but there is no `ToolStrip` on the page.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x0009b] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/gdipFunctions.cs:220 
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.GdipMeasureString (IntPtr graphics, System.String text, System.Drawing.Font font, System.Drawing.RectangleF& layoutRect, IntPtr stringFormat) [0x00053] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Graphics.cs:1953 
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString (System.String text, System.Drawing.Font font, Int32 width, System.Drawing.StringFormat format) [0x00031] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Graphics.cs:1986 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Graphics:MeasureString (string,System.Drawing.Font,int,System.Drawing.StringFormat)
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureTextInternal (IDeviceContext dc, System.String text, System.Drawing.Font font, Size proposedSize, TextFormatFlags flags, Boolean useMeasureString) [0x000eb] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/TextRenderer.cs:263 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText (System.String text, System.Drawing.Font font, Size proposedSize, TextFormatFlags flags) [0x00000] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/TextRenderer.cs:117 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnParentChanged (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip oldParent, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip newParent) [0x00000] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ToolStripItem.cs:1202 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Parent (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip value) [0x0001a] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ToolStripItem.cs:853 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem:set_Parent (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.Remove (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem value) [0x00035] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ToolStripItemCollection.cs:273 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x0003b] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ToolStripItem.cs:962 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownItem.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00089] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ToolStripDropDownItem.cs:185 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ToolStripMenuItem.cs:221 
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize () [0x00000] in /root/mono-3.2.1/mcs/class/System/System.ComponentModel/Component.cs:100
```

Comment: Debugging this without access to any code is difficult. Could you post the relevant parts of the code?